# stale element reference: element is not attached to the DOM - Need to wait until element/ elements visible/enabled using SitePrism

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, capybara, site-prism

I want to use use wait_until method until visible for my element. Currently i am using Siteprism method which is as below. Which is a built in Siteprism method but looks like its not performing well as intermittently it is throwing error (Object not exist in the DOM).

```
@home.wait_until_btn_element_visible
```

So i want to use find method from capybara. Provably which is a better easiest solution. But i having trouble with defining css. As i am defining css in ruby class. I want to use that variable in to below code. How can i do that?

```
page.find('#blah').visible?.should be_true
```

I want something like this :

```
page.find(@home.btn_element).visible?.should be_true
```

Looks like it is not working rather throwing this error below:

```
invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

Need help..... Or any other solution will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

`#find` takes a selector type and parameters of some type, it does not take an element from the page.  Since (after a quick look at the source) it doesn't appear there is anyway to access the parameters specified in your `element :btn_element, ...` declaration from site_prism, there is no way for you to call `#find` without retyping the selector.  That being said there really should be no difference between the `@home.wait_until_btn_element_visible` and what you state you want to do since site_prism ends up calling Capybaras find with `visible: true` specified.  The only difference is that site_prism uses its own wait timeout, so you might want to try increasing SitePrism::Waiter.default_wait_time or specifying longer wait timeout in the wait_until_xxx call

```
@home.wait_until_btn_element_visible(10)
```

Comment: As i said, its throwing this error intermittently:                                   stale element reference: element is not attached to the DOM

Comment: I can resolve it by rescue it and try again. But i don't like it. Need some other good solution /method

Comment: @ASM Yes -- but that error should only raise after the timeout occurs (try increasing the timeout) or potentially if your @home element is found using `#all` or `#first` in which case it can't auto reload itself and you should change how it was located.

Comment: my element (btn_element) is actually elements and i tried wait for 60 secs also . Still it throws the error after 60 secs. But i can see that element in UI, page already loaded with that.

Comment: @ASM what is `@home` - is that from an element or elements definition, or is that a SitePrism::Page object?

Comment: Its SitePrism::Page object.  For element / elements both it throws "intermittent stale element error". I guess i need to use this:      @results_page.wait_for_<element_or_section_name> :count => 25   from this link <https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism>      But i want to use "count > 25" . How can i do that?

Comment: @ASM You probably want to update your question because your requirements are changing.  If what you actually want to do is wait for a certain number of elements to be on the page then you can pass any of capybaras quantity options (count, minimum, maximum, between) - so for more than 25 it would be `@reaults_page.wait_for_<whatever> minimum: 26`

Comment: Same Error thrown for this as well:                                                                 stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @ASM I think you need to re-ask/update your question -  Your question talks about element but now your comments state you're looking for elements.  What you asked for in your question (reusing selector from site_prism in straight capybara find) isn't possible.  When you re-ask/update you should provide some of your code showing relveant parts of your page object declaration and your test code.

Comment: I am getting error on both element / elements. I will add my code shortly